# Thread safety in Server side code

Tags: servlets, thread-safety, reentrancy

I am new to server side coding and JSP/servlets. I have a code which has 3 classes. 1st is a Serv class inherited from java httpservlet. In this i have doPost() method implemented. In doPost() i use object of the 2nd class ResourceClass. ResourceClass is a singleton class. Hence essentially to use any method is do something like ResourceClass.getInstance().readResource();
Now readResource furthur uses Java Native access library to read a resource from disk. Now my question is Since as i understand if 1000 clients connect to my server(Apache Tomcat) for each new request i will have a new servlet serving the request. But all these servlets will essentially use the same singleton object. Hence will this reading be thread safe.

I do not change any internal state. So i think it wont effect my output hence the whole stuff is Idempotent. But will all these requests be queued  making the singleton class object a bottleneck. Or will each servlet has its own copy.

Also if i change the Resource state then in that case will it be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you won't have a new servlet for each request. The same, unique instance of servlet will be used to concurrently handle all the requests. The servlet is also a singleton: the web container instantiates only one instance.

You say that the requests to your ResourceClass singleton will be queued. They won't, unless you mark the method as `synchronized` or use some other locking mechanism. If you don't, then the threads will invoke your singleton method concurrently.

Whether it's thread-safe or not is impossible to say without seeing the code of your singleton and the code of the JNI library. The fact that it's read-only is a sign that it *could* be thread-safe, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks JB. I think i should read some good tutorial about how servlet containers word. Your answer is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java EE server, you only have 1 instance of each servlet. 
On the other hand, each http request is processed by the server in its own thread.

There is one instance of `ResourceClass` because it's a singleton so you will have a bottleneck if the `readResource()` method is synchronized.